# Require() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, reference, markdown, require

When I open console of Chrome 14 and type...

`require` (or `require()`, if that matters)

I get: `ReferenceError`.

This means that JavaScript doesn't have that function by default, right? At least on web browsers.

*Why I'm talking about that?*
I needed Markdown parser for JavaScript.

*What to do?*
I, as usually, opened GitHub and [searched](https://github.com/search?type=Everything&language=JavaScript&q=markdown&repo=&langOverride=&x=28&y=16&start_value=1) for it. The first results that matched my needs was [this](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) and [this](https://github.com/chjj/marked).

Usually (I'm not that good with JavaScript) I include script I want to use before my code using `<script />` tag and then... well - use it. But this time I don't get what's happening... :(

**Usage for #1 script:**

```
var input = "# Heading\n\nParagraph";
var output = require( "markdown" ).toHTML( input );
print( output );
```

**Usage for #2 script:**

```
var marked = require('marked');
console.log(marked('i am using __markdown__.'));
```

Where does that `require()` came from? Thanks in an advice! :)

Comment: See also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41607352/5362795) on how to choose specific identifiers such as a specific function, to achieve similar functionality as `import`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a way to include [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) packages. Luckily, the first package you linked to, [`markdown-js`](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/), is very smart. It checks whether it is included as a node package, and if not, will set the markdown object to `window.markdown`. So all you have to do is include [this file](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js/blob/master/src/markdown.js) in a `<script>` tag and you should be able to use the `markdown` object from the global scope.

Answer (score 5):

From the page you link to:

> The simple way to use it with CommonJS is:

Looks like `require` comes from [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/)

Comment: You can also pack CommonJS/Node.js modules for browser with Webmake - https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake .

Mind however that modules to be ported, should not depend on Node.js native modules (like `fs` or `path`), if it's the case, you need to shim those native modules for Browser (there are already some shims available on Github).