# only require specific exports from a required commonjs module

Tags: node.js, commonjs

In es6 I can do this:

```
const { findIndex, last } from 'lodash';
```

Can I do the same in commonjs with require?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can use destructuring in the same way in node v6 and superior. More info here: [Destructuring in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379277/destructuring-in-node-js)

Example:

```
const { findIndex, last } = require('lodash');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pick parts of lodash to require, there are example on the [lodash docs page](https://lodash.com)

e.g.

```
const at = require('lodash/at');
```